# dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, _dispatchInstances ReactJS error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Hello ,
I was trying to code basket  functions on react(onAdd func). But I encountered such a problem. Could you please tell me why? i have no idea about it .
[You can see problem from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJeJE.png)**

> 

**I tried to add the add-to-cart function to my button, but I am facing such a problem, could you please tell me why?**

```
import { Row, Col, Form, Button, Label, Input } from "reactstrap";

import Link from "next/link";
import items from "../data/products-cart.json";
import SelectBox from "./SelectBox";
import Stars from "./Stars";
import { useState } from "react";



export default function DetailMain({product}) {
  
const[CartItems,setCartItems]=useState(items);
console.log(CartItems);
const onAdd=(product)=>{
  const exists=CartItems.find(x=>x.id === product.id);
  if(exists){
    setCartItems(
      CartItems.map((x)=>
      x.id===product.id ?{...exists,items: exists.items+1}:x
    )
    );
  } else{
    setCartItems([...CartItems,{...product,items:1}]);
  }
};
console.log(product);
  return (

<>
  <h1 className="mb-4">{product.name}</h1>
  <div className="d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row align-items-sm-center justify-content-sm-between mb-4">
    <ul className="list-inline mb-2 mb-sm-0">
      <li className="list-inline-item h4 font-weight-light mb-0">
        ${product.price.toFixed(2)}
      </li>

      <li className="list-inline-item text-muted font-weight-light">
        <del>${product.priceBefore.toFixed(2)}</del>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
      <Stars
        stars={4}
        secondColor="gray-300"
        starClass="mr-1"
        className="mr-2"
      />

      <span className="text-muted text-uppercase text-sm mt-1">
        {product.reviewscount} reviews
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p className="mb-4 text-muted">{product.description.short}</p>

  <Form>
    <Row>
      <Col sm="6" lg="12" xl="6" className="detail-option mb-4">
        <h6 className="detail-option-heading">
          Size <span>(required)</span>
        </h6>
        <SelectBox options={product.sizes} />
      </Col>
      <Col sm="6" lg="12" xl="6" className="detail-option mb-4">
        <h6 className="detail-option-heading">
          Type <span>(required)</span>
        </h6>
        {product.types.map((type) => (
          <Label
            key={type.value}
            className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary detail-option-btn-label mr-2"
            tag="label"
            for={type.id}
          >
            {" "}
            {type.label}
            <Input
              className="input-invisible"
              type="radio"
              name="material"
              value={type.value}
              id={type.id}
              required
            />
          </Label>
        ))}
      </Col>
      <Col xs="12" lg="6" className="detail-option mb-5">
        <label className="detail-option-heading font-weight-bold">
          Items <span>(required)</span>
        </label>
        <input
          className="form-control detail-quantity"
          name="items"
          type="number"
          defaultValue={1}
        />
      </Col>
    </Row>

    <ul className="list-inline mb-5">
      <li className="list-inline-item">
        <Button onClick={onAdd} color="dark" size="lg" className="mb-1" type="submit">
          <i className="fa fa-shopping-cart mr-2" />
          Add to Cart
        </Button>
      </li>
      <li className="list-inline-item">
        <Button color="outline-secondary" className="mb-1" href="#">
          <i className="far fa-heart mr-2" />
          Add to wishlist
        </Button>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul className="list-unstyled">
      <li>
        <strong>Category:&nbsp;</strong>
        <a className="text-muted" href="#">
          {product.category}
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>Tags:&nbsp;</strong>
        {product.tags.map((tag, index) => (
          <React.Fragment key={tag.name}>
            <Link href={tag.link}>
              <a className="text-muted">{tag.name}</a>
            </Link>
            {index < product.tags.length - 1 ? ",\u00A0" : ""}
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </Form>
</>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be in the same format as the data you rendered before.